# AS3 Feather Edge Circle with gradient

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, radial-gradients

I'm trying to draw a very big circle and feather the edge with a gradient

```
        var mat:Matrix= new Matrix();
        var colors:Array=[0x000000,0x000000];
        var alphas:Array=[1,0];
        var ratios:Array=[200,255];

        var size:int = (circleMenu.innerRadius + circleMenuOffset) * circleMenuScale;

        mat.createGradientBox(size * 2,size * 2, 0 ,  0 ,  0);
        circleMenuBackground.graphics.clear();
        circleMenuBackground.graphics.beginGradientFill(GradientType.RADIAL, colors,alphas,ratios,mat);
        circleMenuBackground.graphics.drawCircle(size/2,size/2,size);
        circleMenuBackground.graphics.endFill();
```

The circle is very big, and I want the gradient to start at the last 10% or so of the circle. I can either make it fully black, or disappear, I can't work out how to get a very small gradient. Any clues gratefully appriciated!

Comment: I just tested you code and it worked fine after I changed one line. It should be: `mat.createGradientBox(size, size);`

Comment: Thanks. Yea I just need the gradient to work right at the edge, it's a very big circle and I just want a very small gradient

Comment: So just change the ratios: `var ratios:Array=[240,255];`